# Client can't read more than one message from server (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am trying to make a simple client-server program to help with learning network programming. I aim to build an online chess game but right now Im just trying to do the basics. I have pieced together some code from online sources (MSDN), and I thought it would all work ok. Here is the scenario:

> Client sends **test message** to server
>   Server echos response
>   Client reads response and displays **test message**.
>   Client sends **new message** to server
>   Server echos response
>   Client displays **test message**

The correct output should be as follows:

> Client sends **test message** to server
>   Server echos response
>   Client reads response and displays **test message**.
>   Client sends **new message** to server
>   Server echos response
>   Client displays **new message**

Any and all assistance is appreciated!

Here is the relevant portion of the client:

```
    private void OnlineButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            msg("Response received: " + response);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg(ex.ToString());
        }
        msg("Client started, connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        sessionHandler(2);
    }

    public void msg(string mesg)
    {
        ServerMessages.Text = ServerMessages.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
    }

    public void sessionHandler(Int32 mode)
    {
        switch (mode)
        {
            case 1:
                msg("Starting AI program...");
                break;
            case 2:
                // Create a TCP/IP socket.
                client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect to the remote endpoint.
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                Send(client, "Play Online<EOF>");
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                msg("Response received: " + response);

                msg("Pairing with another player...");
                break;
            case 3:
                msg("Replaying selected game...");
                break;
            default:
                msg("Error handling request...");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is the server:

```
// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
// Thread signal.
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}


public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
```

}

EDIT:

Clarification on the problem:

The client only seems to read the first response the server gives. Example:

> Client sends "Hello"
>   Server echos "Hello"
>   Client displays "Hello"
>   Client sends "World"
>   Server echos "World"
>   Client displays "Hello" (this should be *World*)

Comment: Please specify what is not working as you wished for. Also: your "scenario" and "output should be" contain exactly the same content. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I needed a Thread.sleep(3) after each receive. Fixed it right up :)